# How to fix extreme lag in Diablo III Cinematics?

Tags: diablo-iii, technical-issues

I bought Diablo 3 a few days ago. The game is running quite smoothly, with all graphic and audio options set to the maximum and 1920x1080 resolution.

The cinematics, however, are played with such extremely low performance that I have to skip them in-game and go watch them at YT.

My specs are:

- Core i7 2860QM @ 2.5ghz
- 8GB DDR3
- SSD
- NVidia GeForce GT540M 2gb
- Windows 7 Ultimate 64 (UAC disabled, all drivers up to date)

What must I do to stop the in-game videos from heavily stuttering, so I can watch them in-game instead of on Youtube?

Answer (score 1):

There have been a few proposed solutions on the web, my friend acctually just bought it and is experiencing this same thing.

1. Make sure your graphics,motherboard and soundcard drivers are up to date.
2. Make sure your direct X is up to date (10 or higher)
3. Uncheck foreground FPS cap in the options.
4. See if your graphics card has a built in FPS cap of its own. If so, turn it off.
5. Make sure when you downloaded and installed fully. Some people are saying when they only did the minimal install they are experiencing these issues.

[This](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/4926863865?page=1) thread covers most fixes. And the FPS graphics card cap seems to be the most common culprit.

Comment: 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5, all done. The problem still persists (although the ingame performance had a slight improvement after disabling the ingame FPS cap).

Comment: @FabianN. Bummer, yeah 3 worked for my one friend but not for my other. We are still troubleshooting it. I will update when I have more solutions :)

Answer (score 0):

Solved. The "background update" feature was causing the lag, probably because the video files were constantly being altered by the patcher and I was trying to play them in the meanwhile - seems I missed the "fully" part of item 5.

Thank you very much for the advice btw, Emerica. +FPS is always good. :)